# SwiperJS has undesirable bounce after mousewheel movement

Tags: swiper.js

I am using SwiperJS with React.

Using the mouse wheel produces a strange bounce a few milliseconds after the motion has finished. On wide resolutions, this is not an issue, but on smaller ones it is present.

What is the correct combination of options?

[Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/epic-monad-wrxnkf)

[image]

```
      mousewheel={{
        forceToAxis: true,
        thresholdDelta: 10,
        thresholdTime: 10,
      }}
      freeMode={{
        enabled: true,
        sticky: true,
        momentumBounce: false,
        momentumBounceRatio: 0,
        momentumRatio: 0,
        momentum: false,
        momentumVelocityRatio: 0,
      }}
```